# How to declare multiple enum in a single TypeScript file and return under single export statement (so that not exposing individual enums directly)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, typescript, enums

I want to have multiple enums in the same file and export them under single `export` statement. and when I `import` this single file in another file, I can access any particular enum as required.

What I current have: 2 seperate `.ts` file for Actions and Groups enums,

**First .ts file:**

```
export enum Actions {
   Delete: "Delete",
   Update: "Update"
}
```

**Second .ts file:**

```
export enum Groups {
   Lead: "Lead",
   Permanent: "Permanent"
}
```

**Expected:** I want a single `.ts` file and a single `export` statement. Using this `export`, I can access my both the enums. `something like: Enums.Actions or Enums.Groups`.

Groups, Actions should only be accessed by Enums.Actions or Enums.Groups? some other file should not be able to access individual enums directly.

What is the suggested way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```js
export namespace Enum {
  export enum Actions {
    Delete = "Delete",
    Update = "Update"
  }

  export enum Groups {
    Lead = "Lead",
    Permanent = "Permanent"
  }
}
```

How to use in a file:

```
import {Enum} from "../Enum"
```

We can access using `Enum.Actions` and `Enum.Groups`. Encapsulating enums in a `namespace`, allows Actions and Groups to not directly get accessed from outside.

Comment: will Groups , Actions remain private and can only be accessed by Enums.Actions? By private means, someone else should not be able to access them directly

Comment: i don't know if this makes sense, if you want them to be private, just remove `export` but then they are only accessible inside the file.
if you add `export` it can be accessed from other files.

Comment: I just tested, The idea of encapsulating the enums in a namespace solving my purpose of not exposing the Actions and Groups directly. everyone has to refer this namespace to use Actions and Groups.

Comment: so you can accept my answer? or what exactly is missing?